# Runing server on Windows without deal with the Firewall

Tags: server

**Why is the firewall constantly asking for http permission** for any programms where you need run something in localhost?

When running this example, permission will be asked each time (P.s. Using "go build -o a.exe && a.exe" (Using Go as an example) or something similar may sometimes not help)

**Example 1**

```
package main;

import (
"net/http"
"fmt"
)

func requestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, world")
}

func main(){
  http.HandleFunc("/", requestHandler)
  http.ListenAndServe(":6060", nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In any program where you work with a specific port, where a new executable file is created each time during implementation, the firewall will consider it as a new file and will ask for permission, the solution is the following:

1. Go to **Windows Defender Firewall**, in Left side menu you saw **Inbound Rules** click there
2. Then Right Side menu you will see **New Rule**... click.
3. Choose **Port opened** from window -> **Next** **Select TCP**, then define which ports you want I choose 6060 click **Next** again, Choose **Allow** the connection **Next**, Check All Next, Give any Name Goland or anything you want and press Finish. Thats it
   [image]